# Adding Header button and title for BottomTabNavigator in Vue Native

Tags: react-native, vue-native

I have created a bottom navigator like this:

```
const IOSTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'green'},
        title: 'Home',
        tabBarLabel: 'Homes',
        tabBarIcon: <Icon name="home-outline" size={25}/>,
      }
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: <Icon name="settings-outline" size={25} />
      }
    }
  }
);
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: IOSTabs
  }
);
const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
export default {
  components: { AppNavigator }
}
```

This works fine, and though the header is showing, the title is empty and cannot add buttons or text to it.  I thought that the `title` should display the header but it doesn't.

What am I missing here?